# how to build a svelte customElement using @smui/dialog?

Tags: svelte, custom-element, svelte-component

I want to build a svelte component which can be used along with React frameworks, after read svelte docs, I decide to build my Svelte component to svelte customElement, everything goes well until I used @smui/dialog, my code :

```
<svelte:options tag="charity-legal-agreement-element" />

<script lang="ts">
import Dialog, {Title, Content, Actions} from '@smui/dialog';
...
<Dialog
  bind:this={dialog}
  aria-labelledby="dialog-title"
  aria-describedby="dialog-content"
  on:MDCDialog:closed={deleteItem}
>
...
</Dialog>
```

rollup config:

```
svelte({
        preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ sourceMap: !production }),
        compilerOptions: {
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
            customElement: true
        },
        // customElement: true
    }),
    postcss({
        extract: true,
        minimize: true,
        use: [
          ['sass', {
            includePaths: [
              './src/theme',
              './node_modules',
              '../../node_modules',
            ]
          }]
        ]
      }),
     ...
```

the error from debug console:

[image]

```
index.mjs:1512 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
at new SvelteElement (index.mjs:1512)
at new Dialog (Dialog.svelte:56)
at create_fragment (index.svelte:53)
at init (index.mjs:1489)
at new Src (index.svelte:72)
at main.ts:13
at main.ts:18
SvelteElement   @   index.mjs:1512
Dialog  @   Dialog.svelte:56
create_fragment @   index.svelte:53
init    @   index.mjs:1489
Src @   index.svelte:72
(anonymous) @   main.ts:13
(anonymous) @   main.ts:18
```

if I remove @smui/dialog ,everything works fine, but I need the dialog as a base component, any idea is appreciated~

Comment: You also have to write a React wrapper component for every Web Component, because React now only for 71% supports the W3C Web Component standard. See https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/libraries/react/results/results.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a custom element with Svelte, every component in your app needs to be compiled with the `<svelte:options tag="custom-element-name-here" />`, which makes it tricky to import components from another library.

You could try using the [web component implementation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/tree/master/packages/dialog) of Material UI instead, though it's not 1.0 yet:

```js
// main.js
import App from './App.svelte';
import '@material/mwc-dialog';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        name: 'world'
    }
});

export default app;
```

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<svelte:options tag="custom-element"/>

<h1>Hello world</h1>
<mwc-dialog heading="Test dialog" open="true">
    <div>
        Text goes here
    </div>
</mwc-dialog>
```

Another option is to not compile to custom elements and use [svelte-adapter](https://github.com/pngwn/svelte-adapter) to use the components in a React application.

Comment: Related Svelte feature request: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4228

Comment: thx a lot, by the way ,I copied your code ,it works well but when I tried to get mwc-dialog element, it returns null, what should I do to get the right result(mwc-dialog element)?
```lang-js   console.log('----------',document.querySelector('mwc-dialog')) // null```

Comment: I found a way to get the element ,but it's quite complex
```console.log(Array.from(document.querySelector('custom-element').shadowRoot.childNodes).map(i=>{
    if(i.tagName==='MWC-DIALOG'){
      console.log('element found',i)
    }
  }))
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` won't work because mwc-dialog is in a custom element's [shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM). Try using [`bind:this`](https://svelte.dev/docs#bind_element) on the mwc-dialog element.

Comment: You can also do `document.querySelector('custom-element').shadowRoot.querySelector('mwc-dialog')` if you're outside of the Svelte component.

Comment: thx very much~,I will have a try tomorrow